# Kibana is not starting

Tags: kibana

I have setup kibana and trying to run but getting below exception :

```
[fatal] Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1141:19)
    at listen (net.js:1184:10)
    at net.js:1282:9
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
FATAL { [Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL]
  cause:
   { [Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL]
     code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
     errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
     syscall: 'listen' },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  syscall: 'listen' }
```

I am very new in kibana. I dont understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Most probably it try to bind to a already used port. Default port for kibana must be 5601.

Comment: Your are right. But I have changed the port but still getting the same problem

Comment: just make sure you elasticsearch is running and confirm kibana config files are correct

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem related to the IP address you are binding to, Kibana can't bind to the IP address you provided within kibana.yml configuration, try to set your host as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: For a Docker container on Linux it would be `SERVER_HOST: "0.0.0.0"`